# Creating Database at run time and registering it as DSN at run time

Tags: ms-access, odbc, dsn

I am trying to create an ACCESS DB at run time and register is as a DSN in ODBC.ini using the following code:

```
BOOL fCreated;  
fCreated = SQLConfigDataSource(NULL,ODBC_ADD_DSN,
           "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)",
           "CREATE_DB=.\\ATest.mdb General\0" );
printf("Database created : %d\n",fCreated);

BOOL ReturnResult = SQLConfigDataSource (NULL, ODBC_CONFIG_DSN, 
           "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)", 
           "DSN=TESTDSN_DSN\00DBQ=.\\ATest.mdb\ \
00FIL=MSAccess\00Description=TESTDSN_database\00UID=\00");

printf("Database registered : %d\n",ReturnResult);
```

The first statement returns 1 showing that the DB is created but the second one returns 0 indicating that it could not be registered as a DataSourceName in ODBC.ini. Can anyone please tell me why is this happening because everything like path and name is correct.

Comment: Try calling SQLInstallerError and see what the error is.

Comment: Shouln't you be using ODBC_ADD_SYS_DSN in the first call, or ODBC_CONFIG_DSN in the second, i.e., shouldn't they match?

Comment: I have tried it with ODBC_CONFIG_DSN .... but still it doesn't work

Comment: and I have edited my post as well so that other don't get confused

Comment: The backslashes and 0s don't look right - most of them look like literal 0s.

Comment: I share same opinion but how can I make sure that the format is correct

Comment: There should just be a \0 between each entry, unless it's a unicode string, in which case it would be \0\0.

Comment: I tried that as well but it aint working :(

Comment: how can I use SQLInstallerError ?

Comment: Should be only a single \0 without spaces before and after.

Comment: So, why do you need a DSN instead of just using the DSN-less connect string?

Comment: Agree with David Fenton. Put your time and effort into building a DSN-less connection/tables instead of building a DSN. What will you do if the user account doesn't have permissions to create a DSN? A DSN-less solution will work in such a circumstance but a DSN will not.

Answer (score 1):

It was already mentioned in the comments to the question, but I wanted to provide an answer with some more information:

Instead of creating a DSN by code on some machine, it's probably easier to link the tables DSN-less (programmatically) in the client that will access the database.

If the client is MS Access as well, you can do it with [`DoCmd.TransferDatabase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff196455.aspx):

```
Dim SourceDB As String
Dim SourceTable As String
Dim LocalTable As String

'path to the database that contains the original table
SourceDB = "C:\Your_Database.mdb" 

'name of the original table in the source database
SourceTable = "Original_Table"

'name of the linked table in the local database
LocalTable = "Linked_Table"                    

DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "Microsoft Access", SourceDB, acTable, SourceTable, LocalTable
```